# Can anyone help me with sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am currently writing a database program using Python, SQLite3 and Tkinter. The user enters the unique ProductID and the quantity of said product on the order, and the program takes the price from the product table and multiplies it by the quantity input by the user to give the total cost of the order. Upon running the code, I am receiving the following error:

```
  File "c:\Users\Ryan\OneDrive - C2k\A2 2020-2021\Computer Science\A2 Unit 5\Code\OrderForm.py", 
line 80, in CalculatePrice
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Orders(OrderTotal) VALUES (?)', (price,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

I have done research into this error, however I am completely puzzled on how I can fix it. Has anyone experienced this error before got an idea of what to do? I have attached a snippet of my code and a screenshot of the form GUI below.

```
    def CalculatePrice(self):
        orderid = self.OrderIDEntry.get()
        productid = self.ProductIDEntry.get()
        quantity = self.QuantityEntry.get()
        with sqlite3.connect("LeeOpt.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute('SELECT Price FROM Products WHERE ProductID = ?', (productid,))
            result = cursor.fetchone()
        
        if result:
            price = int(quantity) * float(result[0])
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Orders(OrderTotal) VALUES (?)', (price,))
            self.ClearEntries()
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "No product was found with this ProductID, please try again.")
            self.ClearEntries()
```

[image: Order Form]

Answer (score 0):

The second use of `cursor` is outside the `with` block, so the database connection is no longer valid.

Move it inside:

```
def CalculatePrice(self):
    orderid = self.OrderIDEntry.get()
    productid = self.ProductIDEntry.get()
    quantity = self.QuantityEntry.get()
    with sqlite3.connect("LeeOpt.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT Price FROM Products WHERE ProductID = ?", (productid,))
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        if result:
            price = int(quantity) * float(result[0])
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Orders(OrderTotal) VALUES (?)", (price,))
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "No product was found with this ProductID, please try again.")
        self.ClearEntries()
```

Comment: I thought this would work but I am still receiving the same error :/